# griddb compilation issues

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, griddb

I'm trying to recompile griddb from  source.
I have some compilation errors relative to the templates:

```
./btree_map.h: In member function ‘void BtreeMap::splitNode(TransactionContext&, BtreeMap::BNode<K, V>&, BtreeMap::BNode<K, V>&, KeyValue<K, V>&)’:
./btree_map.h:921:48: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   dirtyNode2.allocateNeighbor<BNodeImage<K, V> >(
```

Using gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

I have tried several versions of griddb without success

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide everyone more details: some scope to what you are doing, what your error is, and what you tried, and also what your end goal is.

Comment: I 'm tryning to build griddb to manage huge time series data.

Comment: And I tryied to recompile it, on Ubuntu x86 server HGX2. I have some compilation errors messages (see msg above) relative to C++ templates. I tried diffferent versions of griddb and ecah time having the same issues. Are there some pre requisits to build griddb, or specific options to give to configure

Answer (score 0):

GridDB only supports GCC 4.8.0 at this point.

On Ubuntu 18.04 you can apt-get install gcc-4.8 cxx-4.8 and set CC/CXX appropriately before running configure.